# Android Image Handling

Tags: android

I am implementing one application in which I am attaching images to issues. These attachments are of two types,

1. attachment by using camera
2. attachment of photo from gallery (already existing photo in gallery)

I getting thee Images as follows

```
//Camera Request
Intent captureImage = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

captureImage.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
startActivityForResult(captureImage, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

// Gallery Pic request
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
```

The result of above is URI. And I am saving this uri.getPath() in my database.

Now problem is when I want to show these images I am fetching it with the help of uri 
I am having. But I am getting following exception after loading first image
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

I read some blogs and I came to know that memory is insufficient for loading it.

Is anybody having working solution on compressing images while showing them in a list.
And recycle memory used after work is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options;
options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( pathToFile, options );
```

This will load only one fourth of the pixels in the image. Change the `inSampleSize` value to load more/less.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

                                        int width = display.getWidth();
                                        int height = display.getHeight();


                                        int bitmap_width = photoBitmap.getWidth();
                                        int bitmap_height = photoBitmap.getHeight();
    // where photoBitmap is your Bitmap image                                   

                                        if(bitmap_width >width)
                                            bitmap_width = width ;

                                        if(bitmap_height>height)
                                         bitmap_height = height ;


// compressing bitmap goes here
                                        photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (photoBitmap, width, height, false);
```